# Invisible subviews in Storyboard view trees

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

[image: Greyed views]

In my view tree in Storyboard I just see my subviews greyed (in some other view controllers only part of them are greyed). They are not visible in Storyboard but work as expected in the app.

This is not really convenient to work on my views design. Any bright idea?

Tried

- I have digged in my commits: nothing that seems relevant. The only weird view is that a couple view has an attribute `misplaced="YES"` I don't get why.
- I have removed myproject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata, that doesn't change anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are 'uninstalled' views. The concept of 'Installed' views (and constraints) was introduced in Xcode 6 along with the addition of size classes.

Basically 'installed' for a particular size class means the view will appear and be part of layout for that size class.

To make them not gray and re 'install' them, go select the views, go to the properties inspector, and click 'Installed' at the very bottom. The views should now appear fully opaque and will now appear at whatever size class in which you are currently viewing this nib.

[image: HUGE property inspector panel]

Comment: A brief explanation of the term *Installed* in this context would improve this answer.

Comment: ... XCode dar magics, so what caused part of my view to disappeared was this XCode update: default is let ruin existing projet... A weird strategy! Thanks for your help

Comment: I need to express my frustration somewhere: this has also completely ruined my constraints... what a joy to do them all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure as Xcode 6 is fairly new to me but i believe that when views are greyed out like this it means that in some size class sizes the views have been removed but not in all.

To test this if you click on the view thats are grey then check in attributes under view that they are installed on all size variations :D hope this helps.

[image: The image below is a button I have removed from any any and only have on constrained width and height.]